# get array from dictionary from NSMutableArray iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have NSMutableArray (self.temporaryArray). How to get "options" key array from dictionary from self.temporaryArray in nsmutablearray. There is console data.

```
self.temporaryArray..(
        (
                {
            "option_group" = 0;
            options =             (
                "<font face=Arial size=2>English</font>\"",
                "\"<font face=Arial size=2>Both English &amp; German</font>\"",
                "\"<font face=Arial size=2>Both English and French&nbsp;</font>\"",
                "\"<font face=Arial size=2>Only German</font>\"",
                "\"<font face=Arial size=2>Only French</font>"
            );
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            "option_group" = 0;
            options =             (
                "<font face=Arial size=2>One</font>\"",
                "\"<font face=Arial size=2>Two</font>\"",
                "\"<font face=Arial size=2>Three</font>\"",
                "\"<font face=Arial size=2>Four</font>\"",
                "\"None of these"
            );
        }
    ),
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you didn't ask the question you needed correctly.

Based on your question, answer is, just store the object at index of the self.temporaryArray to NSDictionary variable and access it from there using "[ valueForKey:@"options"]"

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But I always getting this error : -[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155490d0

Comment: Could you copy some code around it? So that I can debug ?

Comment: self.temporaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.temporaryArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         [self.optionsArray addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"options"]];
     }];
    NSLog(@"self.temporaryArray..%@",self.temporaryArray);

Comment: Try [self.optionsArray addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"options"]]
instead of
[self.optionsArray addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"options"]]

and let me know the result.

Comment: Oh God! Thanks a lot yr... :)

Comment: Thats fine no problem. happy coding.

Comment: Please check it out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535831/create-dynamic-checkbox-in-uiwebview